# Boundary condition for derivative of trigonometric behaving function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics

I want to find a trigometric function for which:

$u(0)=u(1)=0$

and

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(y=0)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(y=1)=0$.

Lets look at e.g. $u=C1 cos(a y+\phi_0)+C2 sin(a y +\phi_1)$.

It is possible to choose a, $\phi_0, \phi_1$, C1 and C2 such that u(0)=u(1)=0, however I can only find the trivial solution in which u=0, to also solve the boundary condtions for the derivatives.

The function u itself should behave like a trigonometric function, but does not necessarily have to be one. So you can also modify the shown function itself. I feel like I am overlooking something very obvious right now, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: "The function u itself should behave like a trigonometric function, but does not necessarily have to be one.": what ??

Comment: I mean it in a way in which also Airy functions behave similar to trigonometric functions for a certain domain before incresing exponentially, sorry I did not articulate myself in the best way possible.

Comment: This clarification does not clarify, on the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

What you believe to be a combination of trigonometric functions with four independent parameters only has two in fact. Because

$$c_c\cos(ay+\phi_c)+c_s\sin(ay+\phi_s)\\=(c_c\cos\phi_c+c_s\cos\phi_s)\cos(ay)+(-c_c\sin\phi_c+c_s\sin\phi_s)\sin(ay)\\=p\cos(ay)+q\sin(ay)=c\cos(ay+\phi).$$

This is a general sinusoid, which cannot enjoy the requested properties.

A possible answer is

$$u(y)=2\sin^2(\pi y)=1-\cos(2\pi y),$$ if that is "trigonometric" enough.